# Only apply a filter if the list count in the query is greater than 0

Tags: python, django

In the following case I only want to apply the `filter(departments__in=depts)` if the count of `depts` list is greater than 0.

```
sites = Site.objects.for_user(request.user)\
            .filter(departments__in=depts)\
            .filter(archived=False)
```

Aside from wrapping the entire block in an if else, is there a nicer way of doing this within the filter?

Comment: have you implemented this filter function or this is coming from some library. If it is self implemented, you can try to skip processing filter when depts==0

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`conditional expressions`](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/52310-conditionals-in-expressions/?in=user-97991).

```
filter_params = ({'archived':False}, 
                 {'departments__in':depts,
                  'archived':False})[len(depts) > 0]

sites = Site.objects.for_user(request.user)\
            .filter(**filter_params)
```

Comment: thank-you, this is along the lines of what I was looking for. I thought there might be a way to apply it all within the filter. I'll mark this as correct if no other answers come that lets me do it within the filter.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply additional filters to a query inside an if block, this in my opinion makes your intention clearest

```
sites = Site.objects.for_user(request.user).filter(archived=False)
if depts:
    sites = sites.filter(departments__in=depts)
```